# Allure plugin for TeamCity: why agent doesn't complete upgrade?

Tags: teamcity, allure

*I've asked this question on Gitter, but answer directed me to the documentation I followed.*

I'm administrator of TeamCity 2017.2.2 with agents running on Windows 10 (except one on 7). I installed [allure-teamcity](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-teamcity) plugin version 2.6 and added allure tools in version 2.6 as [described in the documentation](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_installation_11).

The problem is the tool is propagated to the agent on upgrade, but not the plugin itself. Main server shows me the runner I can use as a build step, but once configured none of agents accept this configuration. I've checked agent directory and logs - the plugin is not there and logs doesn't indicate that there was even attempt to pull.

As a holder of commercial license I asked JetBrains technical support, but they told me I need to ask Allure authors. GitHub sends people to Gitter and here, hence the question after unlucky attempt on Gitter.

What do I need to do to get the plugin correctly pulled and working on agents?

Is allure plugin even compatible with TeamCity 2017.2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Allure TeamCity plugin looks for a tool called `allure-commandline`. So you need to make sure that `allure-commandline.zip` is present in your `<TeamCity Data Directory>/plugins/.tools` directory.